# error validation with jquery validator plugin

Tags: jquery, html, dhtml

this is the complete source for my problem.  I'm not able to display a list of the error messages and elements within the errorContainer.  i.e. if I haven't completed Address1 and Address2 I'm struggling to state this within the errorContainer?  Is this possible?
Many thanks,
james

```
    $(function () {
        var validator = $("#mytestform").validate({
            rules: {
                "data.Telephone": { number: true },
                "data.Mobile": { number: true },
                "data.Address1": { number: true },
                "data.Address2": { number: true }
            }, 
            messages: {
                "data.Telephone": "Please enter telephone number",
                "data.Mobile": "Please enter mobile number",
                "data.Address1": "Please enter address 1",
                "data.Address2": "Please enter address 2"
            },
            errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
            invalidHandler: function () {
                $("#errorContainer").addClass(' error').text(validator.numberOfInvalids() + " field(s) are invalid");
            }
        });
    });

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    label.error { float: none; color: red; padding-left: .5em; vertical-align: top; }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<form id="mytestform" method="get">

    <input name="data.Telephone" id="data.Telephone" class="required" />
    <br/>
    <input name="data.Mobile" id="data.Mobile" class="required" />
    <br/>
    <input name="data.Address1" id="data.Address1" class="required" />
    <br/>
    <input name="data.Address2" id="data.Address2" class="required" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="GO"/>

    <br/><br/>

    <div id="errorContainer">

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: jquery validator plugin (jquery.validate.min.js)

Comment: Do you get any Javascript error?

Comment: this code works..  My question is that I don't know how to display the error messages within the errorContainer?  Can you help?

Comment: It seems you're missing the arguments for the invalidHandler callback function. It should be invalidHandler: function(event, validator).

Comment: how do I echo the messages out?

Comment: Messages should be shown next to the corresponding field. Do you want to display them also in your "errorContainer" div? It's not really clear what you're trying to fulfill.

Comment: I want an error message beside each element that has invalid details, which it is doing now but I also need to have a list of error messages inside the errorContainer which I'm failing to achieve.

Comment: see updated question above for the solution I found.  thanks for all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution.

```
invalidHandler: function () {
        $('#errorContainer').html('<ul>').addClass('errorContainer');
        for (var i = 0; i < validator.errorList.length; i++) {
            $('#errorContainer').append('<li>' + validator.errorList[i].message + '</li>');
        }
        $('#errorContainer').appendTo('</ul>');
    },
```